# Using iPad as keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a second laptop I want to run alongside my first, running Ubuntu of course, and the keyboard is broken and I don't want to unplug my external one from my other laptop for that one, so is there an app like that that works on Ubuntu/Linux as well, or is there a way I can run it through wine (Never used Wine, no clue how to set up an emulation for a keyboard)? Thanks in advance, by the way

EDIT: Nothing? No app?